# Guidance Needed on Integrating OpenAI API for Voice Chatbot with Call Receiving and Answering Features

Tags: text-to-speech, voip, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

Hello **Stack Overflow Community**,

I'm currently delving into creating a **voice chatbot using OpenAI's API** and I've hit a bit of a snag. My core understanding revolves around the chatbot creation itself, but I'm a bit perplexed about **incorporating call receiving and answering functionalities**. To give you a clearer picture, I'm considering two options:

**Option 1:** A basic setup without much online processing.

**Option 2:** A more advanced approach where most processing is done online, using VoIP services (like Twilio) for call handling, thereby bypassing the need to interface with Android directly.

I have a few specific concerns with Option 2:

**VoIP Costs:** I'm worried about the charges per minute and whether the call quality could potentially be inferior compared to regular telco calls. Also, is there a risk of latency or lag due to long-distance connections?

**TTS and STT Services:** The quality of modern text-to-speech and speech-to-text services is impressive, but they come with a cost per word. This adds to the expense, and I'm also concerned about potential delays in data transmission over the internet.

**Bandwidth Considerations:** My current internet setup is 5G, offering speeds between 270 and 650 Mbps at a cost-effective price. I'm inclined to believe that this mobile connection might be more reliable than fiber internet for this purpose.

Could the community provide insights on the following:

Estimated costs for** VoIP, TTS, and STT services**.

Recommendations on managing potential delays and ensuring voice quality.
Any personal experiences or advice on using OpenAI for such a project.
I'm also considering Option 1, which is a simpler setup, but I would like to explore Option 2 thoroughly first. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help and guidance!

**What I've Tried:**

1. Researched VoIP services like Twilio for call handling.
2. Considered using TTS (Text To Speech) and STT (Speech To Text) services for real-time communication.
3. Explored the feasibility of using my current 5G internet setup for this project.

**What I'm Expecting:**

1. A seamless integration where the chatbot can receive and answer calls.
2. Minimal latency in voice transmission.
3. Cost-effective solutions for VoIP, TTS, and STT services.

Comment: Do you know your monthly volume is like? 100 minutes, 1000 minutes or 1m minutes.. Is this something you can host yourself? if yes, I recommend using something like Brekeke (Brekeke.com). You can use their products for your project.